# Django redirect having a ValueError

Tags: python, django

I am having a valueerror on my redirect function below. I checked previous updates which specified that this would occur when the name argument is not specified. I already did but its still not working for some strange reason.

The traceback is below
ValueError at /
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    title = 'Your Dashboard'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            fav_polls = PollFav.objects.filter(fav_user=self.request.user)
            poll_types = []
            for poll in fav_polls:
                poll_types.append(poll.poll.polltype_id)
            poll_types = Ptype.objects.filter(pk__in=list(set(poll_types)))

            context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
            context["submit_btn_value"] = "Send"
            context["title"] = self.title
            context["poll_types"] = poll_types
            todate = datetime.datetime.now().date()

            user = self.request.user

            context["pollsCreated"] = Ptype.objects.filter(c_user=user).count()
            context["pollsECreated"] = PollItem.objects.filter(user_submit=user).count()

            try:
                context["user"] = PUser.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)
            except:
                #where the issue is
                return redirect("PUserCreate")

            return context
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^puser/add/$', PUserCreate.as_view(), name='PUserCreate'),
```

Comment: Why are you returning `redirect` from `get_context_data`?

Comment: @Sachin Kukreja - I am trying to redirect to another url if a created user is not detected.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye - It doesn't work for all my other named urls as well.

Comment: change the `get_context_data` to `get` and the redirect will work.

Comment: But that should not be returning from the context. The method you have overriden is returning a value to the parent class' get method where it is trying to update the context dictionary with the value this method will return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips.

Instead of doing the redirect in get_context_data method, the redirect needs to be done from a get method(below).

"The method you have overriden is returning a value to the parent class' get method where it is trying to update the context dictionary with the value this method will return" - Sachin Kukreja

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

    try: 
        print PUser.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)
    except:
        return redirect('PUserCreate')

    return self.render_to_response(context)
```